# Unable to bind to Slid event in bootstrap carousel from normal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to bind a listener to slid event in bootstrap carousel - For some reason, I can't use `jQuery` in this place and want to use normal javascript

This works

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
    alert("Slide Event");
});​
```

But this does not seem to work

```
document.getElementById("myCarousel").addEventListener('slid', function () {
    alert('slid event');
});
```

Can the listeners not be added using plain js?

Comment: Try 'slide event' instead of 'slid event'.

Comment: The `slid` event (which I assume fires after the carousel is done sliding) is *not* an event accessible with JavaScript alone (i.e. a DOM event). It's a jQuery event, meaning that jQuery is the only way to handle it. If it were a DOM event, it would be listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).